# AChartEngine setTextTypeface not working?

Tags: android, achartengine

`DefaultRenderer.setTextTypeface(Typeface)` doesn't seem to work, is this a known problem? I use the very same typeface everywhere in my app, so it's 100% all right. But if I pass it to the renderer, nothing changes. Using the other `setTextTypeface()`, which accepts standard system fonts, seems to be inoperative as well.

Some source code, although it's more than straightforward:

```
DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
renderer.setAntialiasing(true);
renderer.setChartTitle(title);
...
renderer.setTextTypeface(MyApplication.getInstance().font.condensedNormal);
renderer.setShowLabels(true);
...
```

No error, no message, just the font doesn't get changed, I receive the system font all right.

Version 1.1.0, the latest that I could find.

Addendum: after some testing, it's only the PieChart that has the problem. Others seem to accept the font all right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that this only applies to `PieChart`, I guess I can say it's a bug in AChartEngine. Until such time as it can be fixed, I found the following workaround:

```
public class CustomPieChart extends org.achartengine.chart.PieChart {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public CustomPieChart(CategorySeries dataset, DefaultRenderer renderer) {
    super(dataset, renderer);
  }

  @Override
  protected void drawLabel(Canvas canvas, String labelText, DefaultRenderer renderer, List<RectF> prevLabelsBounds, int centerX, int centerY, float shortRadius, float longRadius, float currentAngle, float angle, int left, int right, int color, Paint paint, boolean line, boolean display) {
    paint.setTypeface(...typeface...);
    super.drawLabel(canvas, labelText, renderer, prevLabelsBounds, centerX, centerY, shortRadius, longRadius, currentAngle, angle, left, right, color, paint, line, display);
  }

  @Override
  protected int drawLegend(Canvas canvas, DefaultRenderer renderer, String[] titles, int left, int right, int y, int width, int height, int legendSize, Paint paint, boolean calculate) {
    paint.setTypeface(...typeface...);
    return super.drawLegend(canvas, renderer, titles, left, right, y, width, height, legendSize, paint, calculate);
  }

  @Override
  public void drawTitle(Canvas canvas, int x, int y, int width, Paint paint) {
    paint.setTypeface(...typeface...);
    super.drawTitle(canvas, x, y, width, paint);
  }
}
```

and then, instead of using `ChartFactory`, instantiating it manually like this:

```
view = new GraphicalView(context, new CustomPieChart(dataset, renderer));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a new features updated in `achartengine-1.1.0.jar` added 
**`Change text font by setting a Typeface object`**.

The added the new method

```
public void setTextTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface typeface)
// Sets the text typeface.

Parameters:
typeface - the typeface
```

so please [update](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list) your library and follow code -

```
Typeface myNewFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "abc.ttf");
renderer.setTextTypeface(myNewFace);
```

hope this helpful to you..

Comment: Well, what can I say? :-)
First, you can see from the source that I _am_ using this function. Second, you can see from the question that I _am_ using this library version. Third, you can see from the edit in the question that some charts work all right, only PieChart is problematic... :-)